# How can I pass the results of find into a function in Bash?

Tags: bash

So I have a find statement in my script that looks like this:

```
find $path -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head -15
```

However, instead of printing the size and name for each of the 15 lines, I'd like to pass them into a function. I've wasted a lot of time trying `while read line; do` but that doesn't seem to work with the `sort` and `find` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function just like a command in Bash, and can use them in a pipeline:

```
#!/bin/bash

sort_head()
{
    sort -nr | head "-${1}"
}

find $path -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort_head 15
```

They also act like a command in another way. A function always returns an integer indicating success or an error code. A function that returns `0` indicates success, any non-zero return is considered an error. This can be seen via `echo $?` after you call a function.

When you pass a function in a pipeline, it's just redirecting the standard output of the previous command to the function. So you could still do a `while read line; do` loop inside the function if you want. In my example above, the output of `find` still gets passed to `sort` just like it did before, and the output goes to your console.

Comment: Ok cool. So hypothetically if the sort_head function took the size and name as argument how would I do that. Would find $path -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort_head '%s %p' work?

Comment: Or would I have to modify the sort_head function to take the $line as an argument?

Comment: I added an example of how to pass an argument to a function. You can just use `$1` as the first arg, `$2` as the second, etc. I also added some more notes about how this works. You can't exactly just pass the name of the file to a function in the pipeline, because technically you're passing "the whole input at once, in a stream". But you can read it with a `while read` loop and *then* call the function for each one, or you can use a loop inside the function above, if you actually need to operate on it line by line.

Comment: The lines are coming in from standard input. So you'd still have to `while read line; do ... done` to actually get the `$line`.

Comment: I tried "While read line" for a while, but it seemed to mess with the head and sort function, because the output of the functions being called wasn't sorted, or the largest files, so I'll try calling it in a loop in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some think like this

```
tmp=`find $path -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head -15`
for i in $(seq 15)
do
  line=`echo $tmp| sed -n "$i"p`
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Find has a `-exec` argument that lets you run a function on what it finds.
The syntax for find is slightly different for different versions of linux. For me it looks like this for a command where I want to find files that are 1 million characters or more and use `ls -l` to display them. `"{}"` is replaced by a result and `";"` is a terminator. Your find may be slightly different.

```
find . -type f -size +10000000c -exec ls -l "{}" ";"
```

Output looks like this:

```
-rwx------ 1 Philip mkpasswd 18902016 Jun  6  2012 ./bin/ffmpeg.exe
-rwx------ 1 Philip mkpasswd 18851840 Jun  6  2012 ./bin/ffplay.exe
```